# Why don't show specific id in action

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am trying to delete by ID. But why don't show `action=NaN` in console.

```
Deleting..  form id="deletecategoryform" action="NaN" method="POST"
```

**Here is my code**

```
<script>
    function handleDelete(id){

       
        var form = document.getElementById('deletecategoryform')

        form.action = '/categories/' * id

        console.log('Deleting',form)

        $('#deleteModal').modal('show')
    }
   
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't multiply `'/categories/' * id`
rather: **concatenate** Strings with `+`

```js
form.action = '/categories/' + id;
```

or by using string [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) with *backticks*:

```js
form.action = `/categories/${id}`;
```

There's more.
When using JS to tackle form submit you might want to prevent the browser of messing thigs up. In such case make sure to prevent the browser to submit the form by using Event.preventDefault() - or actually you don't need a form at all:

```js
function removeItem(ev) {
  const $button = $(this);
  const id = $button.data("delete-id");
  
  $.ajax("/delete/"+ id)
    .done((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      // Remove button's LI parent:   
      $button.closest("li").remove();
    }).fail(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

$(document).on("click", "[data-delete-id]", removeItem);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    Some item with ID 24 <button type="button" data-delete-id="24">DELETE</button>
  </li>
</ul>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```